# How to download a file (JPG) from Firebase to PC with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, download, firebase-storage

This code snippet runs when I push the download button.

What I want it to do:
**Stay on the same page and download the JPG file to my downloads folder**

What it does now:
**Opens a new tab (chrome) and shows the JPG**

How do I fix this?

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref()
const imageRef = storageRef.child('photos/DSC_0305.JPG')
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  var a = document.createElement("a")
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.style = "display: none"
  a.href = url
  a.download = 'file'
  a.click()
```

Comment: Have you tried to add extension to the download property (e.g. file.jpg)?

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using "getDownloadURL()" retrieves the url to a archive stored in your firestore. To download something you need the raw data of the image, not a reference to the image stored in your database. To do so, you can transform it to a Blob like this:

```
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  const blob = new Blob([url]);
  const object = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const fileLink = document.createElement('a');
  fileLink.setAttribute('download', `name you want to your file`);
  fileLink.setAttribute('href', object);
  fileLink.href = object;
  document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
  fileLink.click();
})
```